# Time Domain and Frequency Domain Amplitudes

Tags: frequency-measurement, amplitude

I was wondering about these two graphs, the first is taken from an Oscilloscope and the second is taken from a Spectrum Analyzer.

[image: Amplitude in Time Domain]

[image: Amplitude in Frequency Domain]

Why is the amplitude in the frequency domain close to 1/3 of that in the time domain? The Fourier transform of a sine wave is: [image]. Shouldn't the amplitude in the frequency domain be 1/2 of that in the time domain?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly the amplitude in the frequency domain is in RMS volts.

Divide the pk-pk voltage by 2 * sqrt(2) to get the RMS amplitude for a sine wave.

994 / (2* sqrt(2)) = 351mV.

You have to be careful with the way that various instruments will display amplitudes, they could be peak to peak, peak, RMS or in in decibels (dBV).

Comment: How would I know if it's in RMS on the spectrum analyzer?

Comment: Either on the screen or in the manual - or guesswork! As the other reply indicates it is standard for spectrum analyzers to indicate in RMS. On a mixed function instrument such as your scope however it is not as obvious what would be used.

Comment: One last question. Would I use Vp+ or Vpp? as my amplitude on the Oscilloscope?

Comment: @GarretUlrich **Hameg** seem boldly precise in displaying waveform measurements from their digital samples...many 'scopes make measurements of "PEAK", "RMS", "AVG" crudely enough that I never trust them. Read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum analyzer is showing you the rms level of the sine wave.  Most spectrum analyzers are calibrated to read this way.